# How can I force Keras to use more of my GPU and less of my CPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Running the following:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
```

gives

```
['/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0']
```

Keras can clearly see my GPU, however, when I train my model, the dedicated GPU memory does jump to 7/8 GB, but utilization is only about 5%. Also my GPU memory is 16 GB, so surely it can use more than 7 GB? I have a GTX 1070.

Meanwhile my CPU usage jumps to 30%, which is admittedly less than if I specified the CPU for training.

[image]
[image]

My model is as follows

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, input_shape=(y_ba_tr_in.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True, stateful=False, kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(32, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(optimizer=adam(lr=0.0001), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])


    model.fit(y_ba_tr_in, y_ba_tr_out,
          epochs=300,
          batch_size=5,shuffle=False,verbose=2)
```

Comment: Increase the batch size to increase GPU utilization.

Comment: No, the utilization is still between 5 and 10%. Changing the batch size didn't change the utilization.

Comment: To what values did you change the batch size?

Comment: I changed the batch size from 5 to 80.

Comment: Try something like 256 to 1024.

Comment: Increasing the batch size results in a lower utilization (3%)